# Multiple circle - line crossing performance

Tags: javascript, performance, processing

So I made a game during the pandemic, and I really enjoyed seeing it grow and learn a ton of stuff and implement it.. The game is about small moving circles that cross a line and when they intersect with the line they start to drag the line with them, until a new circle is born again. You can play and see the source code here:
https://github.com/danieledep/REW__P5

The main cross-checking function works like this:

```
p5.disableFriendlyErrors = true; // disables FES

let widthScreen = 800,
  heightScreen = 540,
  wheelRadius = 15,
  tapeStart = {
    x: widthScreen / 3,
    y: heightScreen / 2 - 50,
  },
  tapeEnd = {
    x: (2 * widthScreen) / 3,
    y: heightScreen / 2 - 50,
  },
  theta = Math.PI / 2,
  tapes = [],
  sectionCross,
  crossDirection = 0,
  particles = [],
  targetArea,
  somma,
  bgColors = [
    "#33B1FF",
    "#FD5361",
    "#4CB5AE",
    "#BEEE62",
    "#36F1CD",
    "#F786AA",
    "#1B998B",
    "#6369D1",
    "#FFCF56",
    "#A0E8AF",
    "#F79824",
    "#FCEB00",
  ];

class Tape {
  constructor(x, y, crossDir, movement, wheelMov) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.cross = crossDir;
    this.moving = movement;
    this.wheelMov = wheelMov;
  }

  update(x, y, movement, wheelMov) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.moving = movement;
    this.wheelMov = wheelMov;
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(widthScreen, heightScreen);
  select("canvas").style("background-color", random(bgColors));
  select("canvas").attribute("onclick", "pause()");
  createUI();
  timer = new Timer();

  boundary = new Rectangle(0, 0, widthScreen, heightScreen);
  qtree = new QuadTree(boundary, 4);

  // setup stopped wheels at sides of starting tape
  particles[0] = new Particle();
  particles[0].setup(tapeStart.x, tapeStart.y + wheelRadius, 0, false);
  particles[1] = new Particle();
  particles[1].setup(tapeEnd.x, tapeEnd.y + wheelRadius, 0, false);
  particles[2] = new Particle();
  let point0 = new Point(particles[0].x, particles[0].y, particles[0]);
  let point1 = new Point(particles[1].x, particles[1].y, particles[1]);

  qtree.insert(point0);
  qtree.insert(point1);

  let tapeLeft = new Tape(tapeStart.x, tapeStart.y, 0, false, 0);
  let tapeRight = new Tape(tapeEnd.x, tapeEnd.y, 0, false, 1);
  tapes.push(tapeLeft, tapeRight);
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  //DEBUG QTREE
  //qtree.show();

  checkTimer();
  checkButton();
  checkCross();
  moveLine();

  drawTape();
  drawWheels();

  checkCrash();
  updateUI();
  //getCassetteData();
}

function createNewWheel() {
  particles[particles.length] = new Particle();
  theta = Math.PI / 2;
  timer.resetTimer();
}

function checkTimer() {
  if (timer.isFinished()) {
    for (let p of particles) {
      if (p.moving) {
        let point = new Point(p.x, p.y, p);
        qtree.insert(point);
      }
      p.speed = 0;
      p.moving = false;
    }
    for (let w of tapes) w.moving = false;
    //qtree = new QuadTree(boundary,4);
    createNewWheel();
  }
}

function drawWheels() {
  let index = 0;
  for (let p of particles) {
    p.move();
    p.render(index);
    index++;
  }
}

function checkCrash() {
  for (let p of particles) {
    if (p.moving) p.exits();
    let range = new Circle(p.x, p.y, p.r);
    let points = qtree.query(range);
    for (let point of points) {
      let other = point.userData;
      if (p !== other) {
        if (p.intersects(other)) {
          p.collide(other);
        }
        // check when they are no more colliding
        else if (other.moving) {
          other.moving = false;
          //let point = new Point(other.x, other.y, other);
          //qtree.insert(point);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawTape() {
  strokeWeight(2);
  stroke(0);
  somma = 0;

  //draw static tape
  for (let i = 0; i < tapes.length - 1; i++) {
    somma += int(
      dist(tapes[i].x, tapes[i].y, tapes[i + 1].x, tapes[i + 1].y) / 40
    );

    //don't draw the segments connecting behind wheels
    if (tapes[i].wheelMov != tapes[i + 1].wheelMov)
      line(tapes[i].x, tapes[i].y, tapes[i + 1].x, tapes[i + 1].y);
  }
}

function checkCross() {
  // for each wheel - particle
  for (let j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
    let p = new Particle();
    Object.assign(p, particles[j]);

    // check if it's passing between tapes points
    for (let l = 0; l < tapes.length - 1; l++) {
      // only between those that are not already moved by the particle
      // & not the tape connector behind wheels
      if (
        tapes[l].wheelMov != j &&
        tapes[l + 1].wheelMov != j &&
        tapes[l].wheelMov != tapes[l + 1].wheelMov
      ) {
        let crossDirection = 0;

        // Translate everything so that line segment start point to (0, 0)
        let a = tapes[l + 1].x - tapes[l].x; // Line segment end point horizontal coordinate
        let b = tapes[l + 1].y - tapes[l].y; // Line segment end point vertical coordinate
        let c = p.x - tapes[l].x; // Circle center horizontal coordinate
        let d = p.y - tapes[l].y; // Circle center vertical coordinate

        // Collision computation
        if (
          (d * a - c * b) * (d * a - c * b) <=
          wheelRadius * wheelRadius * (a * a + b * b)
        ) {
          if (
            (c * a + d * b >= 0 && c * a + d * b <= a * a + b * b) ||
            (a - c) * (a - c) + (b - d) * (b - d) <=
              wheelRadius * wheelRadius ||
            c * c + d * d <= wheelRadius * wheelRadius
          ) {
            sectionCross = l;
            //console.log(l)

            // orientation computation
            if (d * a - c * b < 0) {
              // Circle center is on left side looking from (x0, y0) to (x1, y1)
              crossDirection = 1;
            }
            insertMovingPoint(p, sectionCross, crossDirection, j);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function moveLine() {
  for (let i = 0; i < tapes.length - 2; i++) {
    //draw dinamic tape
    if (
      particles[tapes[i + 1].wheelMov].moving &&
      particles[tapes[i + 1].wheelMov].moving &&
      tapes[i + 1].wheelMov == tapes[i + 2].wheelMov
    ) {
      //console.log("moveLine: ", i, " - ", i+1)
      //let q = particles[tapes[ind].wheelMov]
      let leftWheel = new Particle(),
        rightWheel = new Particle(),
        q = new Particle();
      Object.assign(q, particles[tapes[i + 1].wheelMov]);
      Object.assign(leftWheel, particles[tapes[i].wheelMov]);
      Object.assign(rightWheel, particles[tapes[i + 3].wheelMov]);

      //DEBUG
      //strokeWeight(0);
      //fill(20, 200,90);
      //ellipse (leftWheel.x, leftWheel.y, wheelRadius+20, wheelRadius+20)
      //ellipse (rightWheel.x, rightWheel.y, wheelRadius+20, wheelRadius+20)

      let lt = calculateTangent(
        leftWheel,
        q,
        tapes[i].cross,
        tapes[i + 1].cross
      );
      tapes[i].update(lt.x1, lt.y1, false, tapes[i].wheelMov);
      tapes[i + 1].update(lt.x2, lt.y2, true, tapes[i + 1].wheelMov);
      let d1 = dist(lt.x1, lt.y1, lt.x2, lt.y2);

      let rt = calculateTangent(
        q,
        rightWheel,
        tapes[i + 2].cross,
        tapes[i + 3].cross
      );
      tapes[i + 2].update(rt.x1, rt.y1, true, tapes[i + 2].wheelMov);
      tapes[i + 3].update(rt.x2, rt.y2, false, tapes[i + 3].wheelMov);
      let d2 = dist(rt.x1, rt.y1, rt.x2, rt.y2);

      //distance tape in between tangents
      let d12 = dist(lt.x2, lt.y2, rt.x1, rt.y1);

      let distanza = dist(lt.x1, lt.y1, rt.x2, rt.y2);
      //console.log("d1+d2+d12: ", d1+d2+d12, " dist: ", distanza)
      //console.log("tapes[i+1].cross: ", tapes[i+1].cross)

      if (d1 + d2 + d12 - distanza < 1) {
        let crossingBack;
        // Translate everything so that line segment start point to (0, 0)
        let a = tapes[i + 3].x - tapes[i].x; // Line segment end point horizontal coordinate
        let b = tapes[i + 3].y - tapes[i].y; // Line segment end point vertical coordinate
        let c = q.x - tapes[i].x; // Circle center horizontal coordinate
        let d = q.y - tapes[i].y; // Circle center vertical coordinate

        // Collision computation
        if (
          (d * a - c * b) * (d * a - c * b) <=
          wheelRadius * wheelRadius * (a * a + b * b)
        ) {
          if (
            (c * a + d * b >= 0 && c * a + d * b <= a * a + b * b) ||
            (a - c) * (a - c) + (b - d) * (b - d) <=
              wheelRadius * wheelRadius ||
            c * c + d * d <= wheelRadius * wheelRadius
          ) {
            crossingBack = 0;

            // orientation computation
            if (d * a - c * b < 0) {
              // Circle center is on left side looking from (x0, y0) to (x1, y1)
              crossingBack = 1;
            }
          }
        }
        if (crossingBack != tapes[i + 1].cross) {
          //console.log("release")
          tapes.splice(i + 1, 2);
        }
        //console.log("crossingBack: ", crossingBack)
      }
    }
  }
}

function insertMovingPoint(point, sectionCross, crossDirection, wheelCross) {
  let leftWheel = new Particle(),
    rightWheel = new Particle();

  Object.assign(leftWheel, particles[tapes[sectionCross].wheelMov]);
  Object.assign(rightWheel, particles[tapes[sectionCross + 1].wheelMov]);

  let lt = calculateTangent(
    leftWheel,
    point,
    tapes[sectionCross].cross,
    crossDirection
  );
  tapes[sectionCross].update(lt.x1, lt.y1, false, tapes[sectionCross].wheelMov);
  let insertTapeLeft = new Tape(lt.x2, lt.y2, crossDirection, true, wheelCross);

  let rt = calculateTangent(
    point,
    rightWheel,
    crossDirection,
    tapes[sectionCross + 1].cross
  );
  let insertTapeRight = new Tape(
    rt.x1,
    rt.y1,
    crossDirection,
    true,
    wheelCross
  );
  tapes[sectionCross + 1].update(
    rt.x2,
    rt.y2,
    false,
    tapes[sectionCross + 1].wheelMov
  );

  tapes.splice(sectionCross + 1, 0, insertTapeLeft, insertTapeRight);
}

function calculateTangent(pointLeft, pointRight, crossLeft, crossRight) {
  let dst = dist(pointLeft.x, pointLeft.y, pointRight.x, pointRight.y) / 2;
  let angle = atan2(pointRight.y - pointLeft.y, pointRight.x - pointLeft.x);
  let angle2 = acos((wheelRadius * 2) / dst);
  let x1, y1, x2, y2;

  if (crossLeft == 0 && crossRight == 0) {
    //  TANGENT ABOVE

    x1 = pointLeft.x + Math.sin(angle) * wheelRadius;
    y1 = pointLeft.y - Math.cos(angle) * wheelRadius;
    x2 = pointRight.x + Math.sin(angle) * wheelRadius;
    y2 = pointRight.y - Math.cos(angle) * wheelRadius;
  } else if (crossLeft == 0 && crossRight == 1) {
    //  TANGENT UP / DOWN

    x1 = pointLeft.x + Math.cos(angle - angle2) * wheelRadius;
    y1 = pointLeft.y + Math.sin(angle - angle2) * wheelRadius;
    x2 = pointRight.x - Math.cos(angle - angle2) * wheelRadius;
    y2 = pointRight.y - Math.sin(angle - angle2) * wheelRadius;
  } else if (crossLeft == 1 && crossRight == 0) {
    //  TANGENT DOWN / UP

    x1 = pointLeft.x + Math.cos(angle + angle2) * wheelRadius;
    y1 = pointLeft.y + Math.sin(angle + angle2) * wheelRadius;
    x2 = pointRight.x - Math.cos(angle + angle2) * wheelRadius;
    y2 = pointRight.y - Math.sin(angle + angle2) * wheelRadius;
  } else if (crossLeft == 1 && crossRight == 1) {
    //  TANGENT BELOW

    x1 = pointLeft.x - Math.sin(angle) * wheelRadius;
    y1 = pointLeft.y + Math.cos(angle) * wheelRadius;
    x2 = pointRight.x - Math.sin(angle) * wheelRadius;
    y2 = pointRight.y + Math.cos(angle) * wheelRadius;
  }

  let tangent = { x1, y1, x2, y2 };
  return tangent;
}
```

So the game kindof works fine, what really bothers me is that after few circles it gets slow because of the calculations to check if any circle is crossing any of the new lines, until it gets unplayable.

I'd like to ask for suggestion on how to deal with constantly checking multiple crossing, for example when you do collision detection with many particles you can use a quadtree, i'm wondering if there is an equivalent for lines. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I'm using p5.js, you can read the whole code in the github repo link i posted

Comment: Your indentation is messy and all over the place; please fix it in your question.

Comment: While links to repositories are helpful, any code you actually want reviewed must be in the question itself, that is why there is a 64K limit to question size, to allow a great deal of code to be included.

Comment: Fixed the indentation and pasted the main sketch.js file. So you can see my reasoning: I check for line crossing, of all the circles, against all the pair of points of the line. How could that be possibly improved?

Comment: Thank you. After some quick & dirty profiling using Chrome's built-in performance profiler, it seems that the most limiting step in your code is this line, `Object.assign(p, particles[j]);`, at line 171 of your `checkCross()` function. I'm no JavaScript expert, but I'm not sure why you need to use `Object.assign()` when you could simply do `const p = particles[j];` instead and be done with it, since you don't change any of the particle's properties afterwards. I'd recommend you also try using your browser's profiler yourself so you can see exactly what parts of your code are slowing you down.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the object.assign but i can't notice big improvements yet, I'm looking into the performance profiler, even tho I'm not expert in this tool

Comment: @cliesens thank you that was def part of the problem! there were 5 more object.assign and after removing all of these is now way faster, it gets slow after 10 circles, instead of 4/5. i will keep looking into it